# Positive LDO used to regulate negative voltage

Tags: ldo

I need a quiet LDO with very low (few microamp level) quiescent current, but this does not seem to exist as a negative voltage LDO. So the question is, do I need a negative regulator, or can I use a positive one instead, as shown here? The circuit is showing a ground symbol on the output of the LDO. Aside from swapping the GND symbol and the OUT label (which makes no difference to SPICE), it is an entirely conventional use of the LDO. So naturally, it seems to simulate fine. It regulates to approx. -5VDC on the OUT node.

To make my question more specific:

a) does anyone know a reason why this should not work as expected?

b) if so, what problem should I expect and why?

[image]

Comment: What's a "quiet" LDO?

Comment: The difference between a positive or negative voltage is only related to what node we call **ground**. **If** your **only** ground is the OUT pin of the LDO (not the node at the lower right that you call OUT), this would work fine. Realize that then the voltage source V1 must be **floating** and cannot be connected in any way to that ground!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for pointing out to me the obvious reason as to why they actually need to make positive and negative types of LDOs. My application is very particular, and my voltage source is in fact floating. I somehow didn't realize that this was a very particular case, and I was scratching my head about why they make them positive and negative.

Comment: @Finbarr an LDO with a low level of output noise. The output will be further filtered, but it should be low to start with.

Comment: Next time you mention "low", mention **how low**. I might find 10 uVrms quite low because I deal with switched converters all the time that have high output noise and ripple. "Low" doesn't mean anything. Specify it like in a datasheet: 1 uVrms up to 1 MHz.

Comment: That is certainly a good point, but unfortunately I don't know how low, since I don't have any relevant spec for the device that is getting the negative bias supply which I need to generate. But I can say that we are in a regime where no switching supply is tolerated on the board. The floating voltage source is photovoltaic, and capable of giving me up to maybe 50 or 100uA.

Comment: @Eamon in absence of any specs that *you* can give, give the other experts a chance of at least taking an educated guess by describing your application in as much detail as you currently have. **edit** your question to explain what you need that negative voltage for! I'll say: use one of the 50 year old negative regulatorsand a bit of clever shut-down MOSFET logic before if you don't actually have any quietness constraints, which seems to be the case.

Comment: @Eamon I would be careful of using simulation results to validate this, especially with a proprietary model you can't fully see in the insides of.  I say this because many models directly reference node-0 internally, regardless ofwhere you connect the external pin labeled GND.  Luckily, the LT3007 isn't fully proprietary and you can see what I'm talking about by looking at `Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sub\LT3009.lib` starting at the line `.subckt LT3008 1 2 3 4 5` (LT3007 symbol uses the LT3008 model).  Node-4 is the GND pin on LT3007, and node-0 is wherever your triangle ground symbol is.

Comment: You can avoid this by using something like the all-transistor LM78XX model found in `Documents\LTspiceXVII\examples\Educational\LM78XX.asc`.  That way you know for certain the entire circuit description is truly floating. [Note: BJT substrates auto-connect to node-0 by default, but as long as Iss and Cjs aren't defined in the `.model` then the substrate junction doesn't exist.]

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is to provide a gate bias for a cryogenic amplifier, on a board being modified to interface to the cryo amp instead of a SQUID. The board being modified has a predefined interface with no negative voltage source, and noise constraints prohibit using a switching regulator to obtain the negative source. The solution being explored is to use a photovoltaic source which will yield a maximum current of approximately 100uA.

Based on what I've seen so far, I can't see any reason why a positive regulator wouldn't work.

Comment: @SteKulov Thank you for pointing out the possibility of internally referencing node 0, though in a case like this, I would expect such a trick to break the model if used in an unconventional way, rather than make it work. But I agree in general with not putting too much stock in simulation results. In this case however, the simulator just confirms what common sense says should be the case.

Comment: @Eamon that *really* should be part of your question above; very few people will read a dozen comments to understand your requirements! That's why I stressed **editing** your question.

Comment: So, I'm no expert in the board you're planning to modify, but you are! Maybe if you add a tiny bit of info on what the board needs that negative voltage for, one could do a rough estimate of how much supply noise makes it into the signal, and what you'd want to do to keep that low. Other than that, how large is your photovoltaic source? Because 100 µA tells me it's not very large, so that the photocurrent is a result of a relatively (like, still 10²⁰/s or something) low number of photons per second, which means your photocurrent might be a source of noise in itself

Comment: @MarcusMüller to be honest, I'm satisfied with the 'answers' I've gotten in the comments. A few knowledgeable people, yourself included, have looked at the question and failed to point out anything obvious that escaped my attention. In a sense, the question is unfair in that I'm not providing all the details that would let someone fully critique the approach, but that was never my intent, since all I wanted was to know if there's anything obviously wrong with the illustrated upside-down usage of the LDO.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the source I'm currently looking at using is the Panasonic APV2111 or APV2121 (these two look equvalent apart from package), driven at ~30mA. Three of them in series on the LED side, and in parallel on the photodiode. I am also leaning towards regulating the voltage by controlling the LED current with an op amp, and with very slow feedback from the negative voltage - I don't need fast load transient response. As for using the voltage regulator, this is just one option.

Comment: @MarcusMüller regarding the noisiness of the source, yes, I guess we have shot noise here in the photocurrent, so this would set a minimum level for the noise. I can try figuring out how to convert this to noise voltage spectral density, given whatever capacitor is filtering it.... this is actually more obviously an issue if I *don't* use the LDO, but instead use the op amp feedback.

Comment: @everyone: is there a fair and graceful way to mark this question as answered, without being presumptuous enough to post an answer to it myself?

Comment: @Eamon seriously, how many times do I need to stress that you should be **editing**  your question instead of burying info in the comments? Not even reading it this time, sorry.

Comment: @Eamon I think writing your own answer which summarizes useful info given in the comments (if any) is the best way to go for these.  I think the system makes you wait a certain amount of time before it allows you to accept your own answer, but I'd likely upvote it in the meantime.